# What usefulness does having image views of particular mip levels have?

Tags: graphics, vulkan, mipmaps

I know you use mip levels to reduce aliasing effects, but that's done at the sampling level. Let's just say you were only interested in using mips 3 and above you can control that with the sampling. Vulkan offers the choice of selecting image views by layers with base array layer and layer count, and base mip level and mip count. What uses does this have? For example does it have uses for selecting one particular mip, or selecting multiple mips from a certain level onward?

Comment: "*does it have uses for selecting one particular mip, or selecting multiple mips from a certain level onward?*" I don't understand; that's a description of what setting the min/max level in the image view does. So yes, it has uses for doing the thing it does.

Comment: @NicolBolas Can't you do the same thing with setting the max lod on the sampler? Doing it with image views gets you the added functionality of a min lod then?

Comment: Mips are used for oversampling problems, where a triangle might map to very few pixels (or even a single one). Another important feature is when the camera "zooms in/out" on a texture, and during the zoom you want to dynamically blend between two mipmap levels.
Of course, an image view should never exceed the boundaries of the actual number of mip levels in the image that it "views". Selecting a certain mip level may, combined with nearest neighbour sampling, also provide "pixelated" looks. I had one instance, where selecting a base mip was needed bc texture was too large for my scene. etc.

Comment: @alexpanter "Mips are used for oversampling problems," ... Undersampling? The aliasing artifacts you get when you zoom a camera out and the triangle gets smaller is due to undersampling, ie., it samples pixels far apart instead of sampling multiple points in between.  Also when you needed a base mip, couldn't you have set that with maxlod? Instead of creating a new view?